# how to find NIC card Bandwith in linux using native commands

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel

How to find NIC card band width using native commands without using ethtool

Comment: What do you consider a native command?

Answer (score 1):

Without using `ethtool` command. mii-tool will works for you.

```
[root@connect ~]# mii-tool eth0
eth0: no autonegotiation, 100baseTx-FD, link ok
```

Here is another way to find it.

```
[root@connect ~]# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed
1000
```

Dmesg can also provide you some information about your nic.

```
[root@connect ~]# dmesg | grep -i duplex
e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

Comment: You could also  
`[root@localhost ~]# dmesg | grep -i eth0
eth0: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
eth0: intr type 3, mode 0, 5 vectors allocated
eth0: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps`